# Best way to embed a table cell from another website

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to target two cell values, individually, from within a table on another site and embed them on my site.

What is the best practice for targeting and embedding just  x value  from an external sites table? Sorry this could be very basic but I could not find it on any existing forum.

For reference the site is http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/station_page.php?station=41004 and I am trying to isolate the "Wave Height" value and embed so it updates with their table every hour or so.

As an alternative. They do provide a clean widget. In your opinion would it be easier to embed 
 Swell 1.6ft  from here? If so what should I use? http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/widgets/station_page.php?station=41004

Comment: There may not be a way to do this without using a server side language.

Comment: you may look at AJAX (know that there may be restrictions for different server) or possible an iFrame (did i say that out loud)